# Entity Framework retrieve objects based in condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am developing an Web Api application using Entity Framework where I have these two models and my DbContext class:

```
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    public string CourseName{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<Students> Students { get; set; }        

}

public class Students
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    public string StudentName{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StudentAge{ get; set; }

}

//My CourseContext
public class CourseContext : DbContext
{
    public CourseContext () : base("CourseDB") { }

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Students> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I am modeling a WebAPi with these models above and I need to list all students that are taking a course which means that are added to the ICollection Students property in Course Class. I have tried to develop a solution for that but I have no idea how to do that since I do not have a foreign key property between the models.

```
...
using (var course_db = new CourseContext ()){


/*but this return all students and repeated ones since one student 
can be in more than one course*/

var students= course_db.Course.Include("Students").Select(x=> x.Students);

if (students== null){
   return Json(new { success = false });
}

return Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
...
```

I have tried the code below but it did not work. I just want to retrieve the students that are enrolled in a course, since some of them are not. Can someone help me?

Comment: you need to have relation between entities.. why you didn't create?

Comment: You better read [Entity Framework Tutorials](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/) first. It's easy to see that you are not well aware of the basics in EF such as you are not implementing lazy loading correctly. Also, double check your data if what you are expecting matches because if you have different expectations that your data then that's not resolvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to further build relationships in your model. The student to course relationship should be a many-to-many relationship which you are missing the proper properties in each but also a joining table and appropriate model builder (context) configuration.

Override your dbcontext model creation method to add your fluent configuration:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Build many-to-many relationships
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                      .HasMany<Course>(c => c.Courses)
                      .WithMany(s => s.Student)
                      .Map(pe =>
                      {
                          pe.MapLeftKey("Student_ID");
                          pe.MapRightKey("Course_ID");
                          pe.ToTable("StudentCoursesTable");
                      });
    }
```

Add missing Courses from your Student class:

```
    public class Students
    {
        public ICollection<Courses> Courses { get; set; } 
    }
```